# Parametrization of surface of revolution

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces

A surface of revolution is obtained by picking a curve $C$ on a plane and rotating it around some axis contained on the plane.

Choosing the coordinates in a convenient manner, we can pick $C$ to be contained on the plane $xz$ and chose the axis to be the $z$ axis.

In that case, if $R_z(\theta) : \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a rotation around the $z$-axis, the surface of revolution will be

$$S = \{R_z(\theta)\cdot p \in \mathbb{R}^3 : p\in C, \theta\in [0,2\pi]\}.$$

Now, I want to show that $S$ is a regular surface, in the sense that it satisfies Do Carmo's definition:

> A regular surface is $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that for each $p\in S$ there is $V$ open in $S$, $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{x}: U\to V$ such that
>
> 1. $\mathbf{x}$ is differentiable,
> 2. $\mathbf{x}$ is injective,
> 3. $\mathbf{x}$ has injective derivative, that is, $d\mathbf{x}_q : \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is injective for each $q\in U$.

Now, without thinking too much about domains for a while, a natural choice for $\mathbf{x}$ would be as follows: we parametrize $C$ by $\alpha : I\subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^3$ and define $\mathbf{x} : [0,2\pi]\times I\to S$

$$\mathbf{x}(\theta,t)=R_z(\theta)\cdot \alpha(t).$$

This has two problems:

1. $[0,2\pi]\times I$ is not open. Furthermore, $R_z(0)=R_z(2\pi)$, hece we would not have injectivity. This problem would be solved if we replace $[0,2\pi]$ by $(0,2\pi)$ and if $I$ is an open interval.
2. I can't identify the open set $V\subset S$ used with this. I mean, I know that this $\mathbf{x}$ *should* work, but I don't know how to find open $V$ in $S$ for each $p\in S$ so that there is one $\mathbf{x}$ like that.

I mean, defining $\mathbf{x}$ isn't that hard. What I'm finding quite complicated is finding the correct domains on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S$, and then proving inside the domains that $1,2,3$ are satisfied.

How can this be done in this general context?

Comment: Take $x = z$ in the $xz$-plane and rotate around the $z$-axis. You get a double cone and at the cone point there is no way to get the kind of parameterized neighborhood you want, is there? So you'd probably have to slacken the definition, in particular (2). Or ask that the curve doesn't hit the axis of revolution.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of $\mathbf{x}$ is good and your two problems can be fixed quite easily:

1. Restrict to an open set $U \subseteq [0,2\pi] \times I$. For instance, for the point $p = R(\theta_0)\cdot \alpha(t_0) \in S$, you can choose $U = I_1 \times I_2$, where $I_1 \subset [0,2\pi]$ is an open interval containing $\theta_0$ of your choosing, and $I_2 \subset I$ is an open interval containing $t_0$ of your choosing.
2. You don't need to identify $V$ more than saying $V = \mathbf{x}(U)$. If you want something a little more explicit, with the choice of $U$ above, this gives $V = \{R(\theta)\cdot \alpha(t) \colon ~~\theta \in I_1, t\in I_2$}.

In your case, you need to make sure that the curve $C$ itself is a regular curve in order for everything to work. This means that $\alpha$ is differentiable, locally open onto its image and has injective derivative (same conditions as $\mathbf{x}$). This is an assumption that is reasonable to make about your curve.